# PHP Image Cache 

Tags: php, image, caching, facebox, uploader

I have a mini gallery I created and what I did was just used FTP, no database so when I upload a photo it is named "image1.jpg" and then if I upload another image it is named "image2.jpg" and so on.  Well, if I delete image1, then image2 is automatically renamed to image1.jpg and all of them get re-named if there are more.

The problem is that now the new image1 is showing the old image unless I clear my cache. I found a mini solution to work around this:

```
$rand = rand(100,1000);
<img src="images/image1.jpg?<?=$rand;?>">
```

That works fine but I found that it does not work with facebox, whenever I try to view the full-size image in Facebox, it can't read the URL with the random number and it just brings up a ton of characters that usually crashes my browser.

Is there a better way to fix this?

Comment: Why not just leave the image names the way they are when you delete an image? Seems unnecessary to rename the images just because you deleted one.

Comment: Its just how I call the images when I am displaying them, I just use a for loop and count how many photos are in the FTP and then display them all easily.  I have no problem changing around how the Photo Gallery is coded if I have to, just want to see if there is a solution for this method!

Comment: Take a look at what @Jacob wrote regarding the no-cache headers.  That's the approach you want to take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put no cache headers on the image directory.

Comment: Thanks Jacob.  Sorry for the stupid question but what exactly do I do?  I have the following code for No-cache:                        <?php
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Pragma: no-cache");

Comment: Sorry, bad formatting here.  Do I just put that snippet at the top of the gallery page?  What do you mean on the image directory?

Comment: The directory that contains the images should get a no cache filter. This should be done on the server, not via php. [Here's an example of how to do that](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/using-http-headers-with-htaccess.html#prevent-caching-with-htaccess)

Comment: @drew: I upvoted you on the expense of my profile's points. I believe it is not your fault you ain't knowledgeable of the subject matter. What's the point of having this site anyway if everyone expects everyone to ask questions they already knows about?